# Using shadcn components using Next.js pages directory

Tags: javascript, next.js

I can't get a simple shadcn button to work because I can't import the button. I'm using nextjs 13 but i'm still using the pages directory. Here is how I installed shadcn.

Installation command as instructed on [webpage](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation/next)

```bash
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

What I inputed in the command line

```
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript (recommended)? … no / yes
✔ Which style would you like to use? › Default
✔ Which color would you like to use as base color? › Slate
✔ Where is your global CSS file? … styles/globals.css
✔ Would you like to use CSS variables for colors? … no / yes
✔ Where is your tailwind.config.js located? … tailwind.config.js
✔ Configure the import alias for components: … @/components
✔ Configure the import alias for utils: … @/lib/utils
✔ Are you using React Server Components? … no / yes
✔ Write configuration to components.json. Proceed? … yes
```

Basically when I install the button I can't locate the lib folder

```js
// File path: @components/ui/button.ts
//Error: TS2307: Cannot find module '@/lib/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
...
```

Here is my folder structure that was automatically created

```
.
├── src
│   └── pages
│       └── home.tsx 
├── @
│   └── components
│       └── ui
│       │    ├── alert-dialog.tsx
│       │    ├── button.tsx
│       │    └── dropdown-menu.tsx
│       │
│       └─ lib
│           └── utils.ts
├── styles
│   └── globals.css
├── next.config.js
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── tailwind.config.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

Note that this is slightly different from what shadcn has as example of how he structures his. The `@` was automatically created

```
.
├── app
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
├── components
│   ├── ui
│   │   ├── alert-dialog.tsx
│   │   ├── button.tsx
│   │   ├── dropdown-menu.tsx
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── main-nav.tsx
│   ├── page-header.tsx
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   └── utils.ts
├── styles
│   └── globals.css
├── next.config.js
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── tailwind.config.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

Here is my components.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": true,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "styles/globals.css",
    "baseColor": "slate",
    "cssVariables": true
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

and my tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), require("daisyui")],
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` in the shadcn example is not a folder but a path alias.

Move your components and lib directories to the src directory

```
.
├── src
│   └── pages
│   │   └── home.tsx 
├   │
│   └── components
│   │   └── ui
│   │        ├── alert-dialog.tsx
│   │        ├── button.tsx
│   │        └── dropdown-menu.tsx
│   │
│   └─ lib
│   │   └── utils.ts
│   └─ styles
│       └── globals.css
```

Then in your `tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"],
}
```

This means whenever you write `@/components/whatever` The compiler will look for this path at ROOT => src/components/whatever.
And `@/lib/utils` means `<ROOT>/lib/utils`

But with your current config when You write `import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"` It will look for it at `./@/components/ui/button/@/lib/utils` which is not found.

Comment: Ah great! this solved it for me thanks a bunch!